# Accessing meta information formed in ReaderInterceptor/ContainerRequestFilter to use in WriterInterceptor

Tags: java, filter, jax-rs, interceptor

I am trying to log request and response information in JAX-RS. I form certain meta information in the request interceptor/filter that I need to use in the response interceptor.

Is there a way to pass information from request interceptor (`ReaderInterceptor/ContainerRequestFilter`) to response interceptor(`WriterInterceptor`) in JAX-RS?

In Spring, this is not an issue as there is one method where both the request and response are handled.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following way.

```
@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter, WriterInterceptor {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
        String apiPath = uri.getPath();

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> metaMap = getMetaMap(reqContext);

        reqContext.setProperty(Constants.META_MAP, metaMap);
        reqContext.setProperty(Constants.API_PATH, apiPath);

        logRequest(reqContext, apiPath);
    }
}

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    Object apiPathObj = context.getProperty(Constants.API_PATH);
    Object metaMapObj = context.getProperty(Constants.META_MAP);
    Object respHeadersObj = context.getProperty(Constants.RESPONSE_HEADERS);
    Object statusObj = context.getProperty(Constants.STATUS);

    //work with the values

    context.proceed();
}

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
    ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    containerRequestContext
        .setProperty(Constants.RESPONSE_HEADERS, containerResponseContext.getStringHeaders());
    containerRequestContext.setProperty(Constants.STATUS, containerResponseContext.getStatus());
}
}
```

This works, but would like feedback or any better way to handle this.

P.S : I wanted MultivaluedMap and hence passing it from ContainerResponseFilter.

Comment: Your solution is fine. You're using the way it was meant to be used.